# Friend operator + : no matching function for call

Tags: c++

**MINIMAL VERSION:**

I created a minimal version of my program that shows the same error as before. Could anyone explain me why I'm getting those errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename DataType> class Test
{
        public:
                Test<DataType>(DataType Data): Data(Data)
                {
                }
                Test<DataType>(Test<DataType> & Source): Data(Source.Data)
                {
                }
                friend Test<DataType> operator + (const Test<DataType> & T1, const Test<DataType> & T2)
                {
                        DataType NewData = T1.Data + T2.Data;
                        return Test<DataType>(NewData);
                }
        protected:
                DataType Data;
};

int main()
{
        Test<string> T1(string("Foo"));
        Test<string> T2(string("Bar"));

        auto T3 = T1 + T2;
        return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall
```

Compiler result:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:29:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >::Test(Test<std::basic_string<char> >)’
test.cpp:29:17: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:12:3: note: Test<DataType>::Test(Test<DataType>&) [with DataType = std::basic_string<char>]
test.cpp:12:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >&’
test.cpp:9:3: note: Test<DataType>::Test(DataType) [with DataType = std::basic_string<char>]
test.cpp:9:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>’
test.cpp: In function ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> > operator+(const Test<std::basic_string<char> >&, const Test<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
test.cpp:29:17:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:18:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >::Test(Test<std::basic_string<char> >)’
test.cpp:18:33: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:12:3: note: Test<DataType>::Test(Test<DataType>&) [with DataType = std::basic_string<char>]
test.cpp:12:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >&’
test.cpp:9:3: note: Test<DataType>::Test(DataType) [with DataType = std::basic_string<char>]
test.cpp:9:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Test<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>’
```

**OLD VERSION:**

I have a template class called Buffer. I did implemenation in the header file. I want to create a overload for + operator to be able to call lets say

```
auto Buffer3 = Buffer1 + Buffer2
//Where Buffer1 and Buffer2 are Buffer<string>
```

I created a function inside of class{};:

```
friend Buffer<ElementType> operator + (Buffer<ElementType> & B1, Buffer<ElementType> & B2)
{
    Buffer Output(B1.GetElementsNum() + B2.GetElementsNum(), B1.Overwrite || B2.Overwrite);
    Output += B1;
    Output += B2;
    return Output;
}
```

**When I compile it in Visual Studio everything is OK, it works fine etc.**

**When I compile it using g++ with -std=c++0x I'm getting:**

```
Testing.h:57:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘Buffer<std::basic_string<char> >::Buffer(Buffer<std::basic_string<char> >)’
Testing.h:57:30: note: candidates are:
Buffer.h:16:3: note: Buffer<ElementType>::Buffer(Buffer<ElementType>&) [with ElementType = std::basic_string<char>]
Buffer.h:16:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Buffer<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘Buffer<std::basic_string<char> >&’
```

Testing.h:57 is:

```
auto B3 = B1 + B2;
```

Buffer.h:16 is my copy construct of class Buffer

**SOLUTION:**

Make a copy constructor argument **const**

Comment: const correctness: Make the arguments `const Buffer<ElementType> &` - msvc is wrong here

Comment: @DieterLücking Aw, the answers in the comments...

Comment: @luk32 After some development my answer (same as my comment) has become useless - thats why.

Comment: @peku33 There's no need to edit the solution into your question here on SO. It's already there in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to your copy constructor isn't `const`, so the temporary returned by the addition can't be bound to it.

The capability of binding a temporary to non-const reference is an infamous Visual C++ "extension" to the language.

Comment: An "extension" only created to make anyone suffer horrible pain who's trying to port something to Linux. Another one of your "great" ideas, MS.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your follow up question: Same issue as before, but with your copy ctor:

```
// Make that a const &
Test<DataType>(const Test<DataType> & Source)
```

After making the argument const, it compiles fine.